# Android TextView autoLink web Bug

Tags: android

I have a TextView like this.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_auto_linkify"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/link_text_auto" />
```

and the @string/link_text_auto" like this

```
<string name="link_text_auto"><b>text_auto_linkify: Various kinds
  of data that will be auto-linked.</b>\n
  1. In this text are some things that are actionable.\n
  1.In this text are some things that are actionable.
</string>
```

notice the text, that the first one has space after "1."

and the result is out of my expectation.

[1.In this text are some things that are actionable.] Android thinks it's a hyperlink.

so is there anyone can tell me,why?
my phone is Moto X
and the android version is 5.1.1